# Jackson Json serialization

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-modules

I'm using Jackson 2.4 and I need to generate data to be process by d3.js.

d3.js want my json values to be format like this :

```
values : [[0, 13.5],[1, 2.5],[2, 5],[3, 41.2]]
```

In my Java model I have :

```
public class Series {

    private String key;
    private List<Entry> values;

    ...

    public void addEntry(int x, double y) {
        values.add(new Entry(x, y));
    }

    public class Entry {
        private int x;
        private double y;

        ...        
    }
}
```

It is only for serialization, not for deserialization, so is there a way with Jackson annotation to have the json generate as I want because for now it generates this :

```
values : [{x: 0, y: 13.5},{x: 1, y: 2.5},{x: 2, y: 2, 5},{x: 3, y: 41.2}]
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to use `@JsonValue`. Try adding this to your `Entry` class:

```
@JsonValue
public Object[] jsonArray() {
    return new Object[]{Integer.valueOf(x), Double.valueOf(y)};
}
```

(You could also return a `double[]`, since this is just going to get converted to a JavaScript number, or use autoboxing, but this is a bit clearer IMO.)